# Cannot Install Sync Framework on Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, installation, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to install the Sync Framework 2.1 (SyncSDK-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi) on my Windows 8.1 machine but the installer complains that it required .Net Framework 2.0 or greater.

The problem is i already have it installed as other versions of .Net.

My installed Versions

1. v2.0.50727
2. v3.0
3. v3.5
4. v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this is probably silly answer, but did you check *.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)* option in *Programs and Features* | *Turn Windows features on or off* ?

I had the same problem, but it went away after I turned this on.

HTH, Tom